# Java socketConnection - Different Console for server and client?

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I am using Eclipse Luna on Mac.

And, I am studying Server/Client things...  (Example below)

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket( 8000 );
System.out.println("How May I Serve You?"+" ("+date.toString()+")");
Socket socketConnection = serverSocket.accept();    
DataOutputStream dosToClient = new DataOutputStream(socketConnection.getOutputStream() );
DataInputStream  disFromClient = new DataInputStream(socketConnection.getInputStream() );
```

But I see outputs and actions of server/client on single console screen..

can anyone tell me how to have multiple console screens for both server and client?

Answer (score 0):

You have yet to create a client connection.The above code has just the server side of the request.You could create a separate java client and execute the same in a different console.
See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm

Comment: Oh no , I have all the codes.. that's just an example to show you what I am doing..

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you wish to accomplish .If you have two separate java files for the client and server,you must be able to execute them in different consoles.